# EF 6 | Timeout error on inserting into database, but works fine on another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working with a friend on a project. I am now running the code on my system, but for me, I receive this error when I try to create a record in the SQL server database.

[image]

When he runs it on his system, it updates without any issues.

If I add this code to the context startup it works for me, but takes time!

```
        public FileContext()
            : base("name=FileContext")
        {
            var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
            var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
            objectContext.CommandTimeout = 1 * 60; // value in seconds
        }
```

What is set wrong that would cause this?

We shouldn't have to touch the timeout if it works on his computer and has for this entire time?

**Update:**

The GET call to the database on the same table is working fine, but the inserts into the table cause timeouts.

**Update 2:**
After the below comment, I took the query directly to SQL Server and it takes 40 seconds on the server. It is a simple insert statement. On another database, it works fine.

Comment: is SQL server available on your system? Probably for a string connection.

Comment: @thisisnabi: Yes, it is working fine. The get call to pull the data doesn't time out and works fine. The insert into the database fails though.

Comment: The DB operation is probably just too slow on your system. The execution time can vary based on the data in your DB and the performance of your machine. Try running the SQL (generated by EF) manually using a tool like SSMS to see how long it takes to run. You can grab the generated SQL from EFs log output.

Comment: @musium: yes, when I create the Insert in SQL Server, it still takes long. This insert should take less than a second. What else could be blocking it on my SQL Server? It doesn't appear to be EF Core.

Comment: @tvb108108 Now that you know that it is not an EF problem you can focus on the DB. The execution plan of your query will tell you what causes the query to be slow. Common problems are missing/wrong or too many 
 indexes, wrong datatypes (eg. ntext vs varchar(lenght)), "expansive" functions in your query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

I had to rebuilt the Indexes on the table that was seeing the slowness into SQL Server.

Went to SSMS -> Databases -> problematic Table -> Indexes -> Rebuild indexes

[image]

Comment: How did you determine this was the issue ?